# Getting error that variable doesn't exist

Tags: apex

I am writing a webservice & getting an error:

> Variable does not exist: Cal  Could use little help :)

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Sync/*')                            
 global class CreatrixSync{

 @HttpPost
  global static String doPost(String application_email, String application_mobile, String application_program, ) {

        External_System_Mapping__c[] LeadProgram = [SELECT Salesforce_Value__c from External_System_Mapping__c
                WHERE Mapping_Type__c = 'Program' 
                AND External_System_Value__c =:application_program ];

        if(LeadProgram.size() > 0 && LeadProgram[0].Salesforce_Value__c != 'No Program')
         {
           Calender__c[] Cal = [SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Program__c, Intake_Month__c, Intake_Year__c 
                FROM Calender__c
                WHERE Start_Date__c <= :System.Today() 
                AND End_Date__c >= :System.Today() and Program__c = :LeadProgram[0].Salesforce_Value__c]; 
        } 
        List<Lead> matchingLeadsListWIProgram;
        if (leadProgram != null && leadProgram.size() > 0) {
            matchingLeadsListWIProgram = [Select Id, Status from Lead where isConverted = false and ((Program__c =: LeadProgram[0].Salesforce_Value__c) and ( (Email != null AND Email = :application_email) OR (MobilePhone != null AND MobilePhone = :application_mobile) OR (Email != null AND Email=:spjat_email) OR (MobilePhone != null AND MobilePhone =:spjat_mobile))) ];
        }else{
            matchingLeadsListWIProgram = null;
        }

        if(matchingLeadsListWIProgram != null && matchingLeadsListWIProgram.size() > 0){ 
            for(Lead lead : matchingLeadsListWIProgram ){

                   //some code             
                if(Cal.size()>0){
                 lead.Intake__c = Cal[0].id;
                }      

         }

            update matchingLeadsListWIProgram;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple [scoping](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_variables.htm) issue. A variable only exists between `{` and `}`. You need to move the variable outside of the if statement. Here's a revision:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Sync/*')                            
global class CreatrixSync{
    @HttpPost
    global static String doPost(String application_email, String application_mobile, String application_program) {

        Calender__c[] Cal = new Calendar__c[0];
        List<Lead> matchingLeadsListWIProgram = new Lead[0];

        External_System_Mapping__c[] LeadProgram = [Select Salesforce_Value__c from External_System_Mapping__c Where Mapping_Type__c = 'Program' and External_System_Value__c =:application_program ]; 
        if(LeadProgram.size() > 0 && LeadProgram[0].Salesforce_Value__c != 'No Program'){
          Cal = [SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Program__c, Intake_Month__c, Intake_Year__c FROM Calender__c WHERE Start_Date__c <= :System.Today() and End_Date__c >= :System.Today() and Program__c = :LeadProgram[0].Salesforce_Value__c]; 
        } 
        if (leadProgram.size() > 0) {
            matchingLeadsListWIProgram = [Select Id, Status from Lead where isConverted = false and ((Program__c =: LeadProgram[0].Salesforce_Value__c) and ( (Email != null AND Email = :application_email) OR (MobilePhone != null AND MobilePhone = :application_mobile) OR (Email != null AND Email=:spjat_email) OR (MobilePhone != null AND MobilePhone =:spjat_mobile))) ];
        }
        for(Lead lead : matchingLeadsListWIProgram ){
            if(Cal.size()>0){
                 lead.Intake__c = Cal[0].id;
            }      
        }
        update matchingLeadsListWIProgram;
    }
}
```

You'll notice also how I simplify the code by initializing the variables with an empty list.